# Loading thousands of pins(multi markers) with Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have searched google and this site for a solution, and have tried many approaches, none of which solve my problem.

I'm using a standard approach for adding multi-markers to my GMaps app with javascript. I found that after a certain amount of pins(1000+), the pins no longer show up on the map :(

**My question: is it possible to load 1000-to-10000 pins with Google Maps??**

Can someone please explain why there is a limit for pins with Google Maps API v3??

Assuming that Google Maps does not support my requirement for loading thousands of pins, are there any other similar APIs which can load thousands of pins??

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no such limit, check this page:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#markers -- I succesfully loaded 10000 markers on this google map:

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

    // Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                              southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
      map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
    }
  }
}
```

But as the number of markers increase, there could be required more time for the web browser to process them.